# Creating a Variable Initial Values from a base variable in Panel Data Structure in R

Tags: r, transform, panel

I'm trying to create a new variable in R containing the initial values of another variable (crime) based on groups (countries) considering the initial period of time observable per group (on panel data framework), my current data looks like this:

| country | year | Crime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2016 | 2.7369478 |
| Albania | 2017 | 2.0109779 |
| Argentina | 2002 | 9.474084 |
| Argentina | 2003 | 7.7898825 |
| Argentina | 2004 | 6.0739941 |

And I want it to look like this:

| country | year | Crime | Initial_Crime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | 2016 | 2.7369478 | 2.7369478 |
| Albania | 2017 | 2.0109779 | 2.7369478 |
| Argentina | 2002 | 9.474084 | 9.474084 |
| Argentina | 2003 | 7.7898825 | 9.474084 |
| Argentina | 2004 | 6.0739941 | 9.474084 |

I saw that ddply could make it work this way, but the problem is that it is not longer supported by the latest R updates.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `arrange` by `year`, then after grouping by `country` set `Initial_Crime` to be the `first` `Crime` in the group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(Initial_Crime = first(Crime))
```

**Output**

```
  country    year Crime Initial_Crime
  <chr>     <int> <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Argentina  2002  9.47          9.47
2 Argentina  2003  7.79          9.47
3 Argentina  2004  6.07          9.47
4 Albania    2016  2.74          2.74
5 Albania    2017  2.01          2.74
```

Comment: sorry @Ben - didn't mean to edit your post - I rolled back - was trying to edit my own!

Comment: @langtang No problem!

Comment: @Ben this was the easiest solution and also the one which I managed to pull up a logical sense, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, Initial_Crime:=.SD[1,Crime], by=country]

     country year    Crime Initial_Crime
1:   Albania 2016 2.736948      2.736948
2:   Albania 2017 2.010978      2.736948
3: Argentina 2002 9.474084      9.474084
4: Argentina 2003 7.789883      9.474084
5: Argentina 2004 6.073994      9.474084
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution

```
setDT(df)

df[, x := 1:.N, country
   ][x==1, initial_crime := crime
     ][, initial_crime := nafill(initial_crime, type = "locf")
       ][, x := NULL
         ]
```